# Probability the minimum is three when three dice are rolled

Tags: probability

I want the probability that the minimum is three when three dice are rolled.

First, we have $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$ configurations.

Then, if the minimum is three we have to select $3,4,5$ and $6$ on the dice. $1 \cdot 4 \cdot 4=16$, and we can do this three times, $4 \cdot 1 \cdot 4$ and $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 1$. Therefore we have $16 \cdot 3 = 48$ configurations that the minimum is three, and the probability is $48/(16)^3$.

What is the mistake?

Comment: Which of the "1x4x4" vs "4x1x4" or "4x4x1" scenarios do you count having rolled all threes?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is again that you are overcounting scenarios with multiple 3's rolled in each of your three cases.  (*You also have a typo, having written $16^3$ instead of $6^3$ in your denominator*).

To correct your approach, we can do a number of things.  We could break into cases based on the timing in which we first see a $3$.  That would make your cases of size $1\times 4\times 4$ for the case the first three is seen in the first position... of size $\color{red}{3}\times 1\times 4$ for the case of the first three seen in the second position (*noting that then the first position could not have been a 3*), and of size $\color{red}{3}\times\color{red}{3}\times 1$ for the third case.

This gives an answer of $\dfrac{16+12+9}{6^3}=\dfrac{37}{216}$

We could also have broken into cases by how many 3's were seen and where... giving $\binom{3}{1}\cdot (1\times 3\times 3)+\binom{3}{2}\cdot(1\times 1\times 3)+\binom{3}{3}(1\times 1\times 1) = 27+9+1=37$ cases, again leading to $\dfrac{37}{216}$

Yet another way to fix your answer is by inclusion-exclusion... $\binom{3}{1}\cdot (1\times 4\times 4)-\binom{3}{2}\cdot(1\times 1\times 4)+\binom{3}{3}\cdot(1\times 1\times 1) = 3\cdot 16 - 3\cdot 4 + 1 = 37$ leading to the same answer as before.

---

My preferred way to solving this is in recognizing $$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(X\geq 3)-\Pr(X>3) = \dfrac{4^3}{6^3}-\dfrac{3^3}{6^3}=\dfrac{37}{216}$$