Min of Dice Roll Problem - Not sure how I am wrong
Three fair dice are rolled and $X$ is the min. Find $P(X=3)$.
I do not understand how my solution is incorrect. The answer is $37/216$.
My solution: Pick a dice to be the min ($3$ ways). Make that dice a $3$ (with prob. $1/6$). For the last two dice, make them at least a six with prob. $(4/6)^2$. I get $27/216$ prob, which evidently is undercounting.
This also agrees with the formula for the pmf of the first order-stat, so I fail to see how it is not correct.
Thanks.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

This will be a duplicate.  An easy approach if to find the probability all three dice show $3$ or more and subtract the probability all four dice show $4$ or more.  I suspect "This also agrees with the formula for the pmf of the first order-stat" is wrong; what are the probabilities for $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and do these add up to $1$?

As an example of an earlier question (thought there are others): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593687/probability-the-minimum-is-three-when-three-dice-are-rolled

Mutually exclusive events: probability the first die is $3$ and the others are $3$ or more is $\frac16 \times \frac46 \times \frac46$; probability the first die is more than $3$, the second is $3$ and the third is $3$ or more is  $\frac36 \times \frac16 \times \frac46$; probability the first two dice are more than $3$ and the third is $3$ is  $\frac36 \times \frac36 \times \frac16$. Add these up to get $\frac{16+12+9}{216}$.

My preferred way to solve this is by recognizing
$$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(X≥3)−\Pr(X>3)= 4^3/6^3 - 3^3/6^3 =37/216.$$
The part where you might be getting wrong is that you are overcounting scenarios with multiple $3$'s rolled in each of your three cases.

I see. So, to be sure, I am counting the outcomes where the first slot is the min (and so 3) and the last two are three, plus the outcome where the second slot is the min (and so 3), and the rest are tree, etc.. EDIT: and my answer had (4/6)^2 not (3/6)^2

When the minimum is three, it is possible that one, two or all of the dice show a three.
If one of the dice shows a three, then the other two dice can be $4$, $5$ or $6$. Since there are three ways for one of the dice to show a $3$ and three possibilities for each of the other two dice, we get $3\times 3^2=27$ ways to get a minimum of three with only one die showing $3$.
There are three ways for two of the dice to show a $3$ times $3$ possibilities for the remaining die which gives $9$.
Finally, there is one way to get all three dice to show a $3$.
Therefore, there are $27+9+1=37$ ways for the minimum to be a $3$.

In order to see the error, i will insert one step in front of the OP steps, let us order the values. So let us analyze:


Step $0$: Three numbers $a,b,c$ with values in $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ are chosen independently with values equally probable.


Step $1$: Let $A,B,C$ be the same values, but ordered so that $A\le B\le C$. Then there are the following sub-cases:

$A=B=C$ ,
$A=B<C$ ,
$A<B=C$ ,
$A<B<C$ .


Step $2$: We analyze the subcases having $A=3$.

If $A=B=C$ we have one match, the $(3,3,3)$.
If $A=B<C$ we have three$=\binom 31$ matches, the cases $(3,3,C)$ with $C\in{4,5,6}$.
If $A<B=C$ we have three$=\binom 31$  matches, the cases $(3,B,B)$ with $B\in{4,5,6}$.
If $A<B<C$ we have three=$\binom 32$ matches, the cases $(3,B,C)$ with $B,C\in{4,5,6}$, two different choices taken from three possibilities.


Step $3$: The possibilities separated in $A,B,C$-cases do not show up with equal probability in terms of the $(a,b,c)$ cases. Explicitly:

If $A=B=C$ we have one match, the $(3,3,3)$, it corresponds to only one $(a,b,c)$-case, which is $(3,3,3)$. So the contribution to the total probability $P(X=3)$ is:
$$P(X=3\ \cap\ \text{(all three numbers $a,b,c$ are equal) })=\frac 1{6^3}\ .
$$
If $A=B<C$ we have $3$ $(A,B,C)$-cases $(3,3,C)$ with $C\in{4,5,6}$,
each case coming from three other $(a,b,c)$-cases, since $(A,B,C)=(3,3,C)$ may come from $(a,b,c)$ among $(C,3,3)$, $(3,C,3)$, $(3,3,C)$.
so the corresponding piece to $P(X=3)$ is
$$P(X=3\ \cap\ \text{(exactly two numbers among $a,b,c$ are $3$) })=\frac {3\cdot 3}{6^3}\ .
$$
If $A<B=C$ we have $3$ $(A,B,C)$-cases $(3,B,B)$ with $B\in{4,5,6}$,
each case coming from three other $(a,b,c)$-cases, since $(A,B,C)=(3,B,B)$ may come from $(a,b,c)$ among $(B,B,3)$, $(B,3,B)$, $(3,3,B)$.
So the corresponding piece to $P(X=3)$ is
$$P(X=3\ \cap\ \text{(exactly one number among $a,b,c$ is $3$, the others being equal) })=\frac {3\cdot 3}{6^3}\ .
$$
If finally $A<B<C$ we have three matches, and each of the $(A,B,C)$-cases $(3,B,C)$ with $B,C\in{4,5,6}$, shows up in $3!=6$ ways in terms of $(a,b,c)$, all possible permutations.
So the corresponding piece to $P(X=3)$ is
$$P(X=3\ \cap\ \text{(exactly one number among $a,b,c$ is $3$, the others being **not** equal) })=\frac {3\cdot 3!}{6^3}\ .
$$


Putting all together, we obtain the probability:
$$
P(X=3)
=
\frac 1{6^3}(1+9+9+18)
=
\frac {37}{6^3}\ .
$$

The "tentative solution", as it is suggested by OP, makes in the above counting (which is by far not the simplest) argument the following error(s):
Instead of counting and getting the sum $(1+9+9+18)=37$ we only get $(\color{red}{0}+\color{red}{0}+9+18)$. Namely the cases in which the minimal value $3$ is taken exactly once, thus matching only the cases $(3,B,B)$ and $(3,B,C)$.

Note: This is an answer to the question "Where is the counting error?"
The question "How to count in a simple, natural manner?" is easier. If the minimal value is $3$, then all the three values $a,b,c$ are among $3,4,5,6$, and the cases when they are all in $4,5,6$ must be excluded, so there are $4^3-3^3=64-27=37$ such "good" cases.
